# Blackberry application in SUP 2.0

Tags: blackberry, sup

I am developing a blackberry application in SUP 2.0, in which I need to fetch data from SAP ECC 6.0 based on two input values on the devices. For this I had created two synchronization parameters and mapped the synchronization parameters to the load parameter of the MBO (which get automatically generated since my RFC is having two import parameters).

I know, the version of SUP is 1.5.5, this can be easily achieved. But I am developing application in SUP 2.0 and my user interface to the application using Mobile Workflow form editor. I added two editboxes to the start screen and add a menu item in which i assign the MBO.

Can anybody please help me how to map the editbox values to the synchronization parameter values, so that I can pass the entered value to the RFC and fetch value from baclend based on the entered value ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define a control that will map the load parameters to the object query that fetches that data.

Check out the documentation [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01206.0200/doc/html/mqu1297271756950.html).

This may not be *exactly* what you are looking for, but I think the approach will probably get you a little farther.